# c# Wpf application different behavior

Tags: c#, xml

I hope someone can help me, as I can not find the solution myself. (I know Google is my friend..etc)
So, I have a relatively simple c# application (it reads a specific XML node from three different XML files and then adds these nodes innerText to a combobox. - for find and replace)
The application runs fine on my own work and home computer both in VS debug mode and as .exe. 
But when I sent the .exe file to my colleagues (from 3 people, 2 failed) they have experienced that the program started but the combobox was empty.
(all computers are running Win 10, no restrictions on the office computers, all windows updates are installed)
So I'm out of ideas...

Comment: We can't possibly know. Add logging to your app.

Comment: does everyone have the .NET version installed that your are using with your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the excellent suggestion of adding logging (loads of it, at every relevant line of code for debugging purposes), if you're using WPF, you can also use [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/), which will allow you to dig into the binding, which can be very helpful.